# How to customize 403 error exception in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have put the following files in

`/app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception`

```
error.html.twig, error.json.twig , error403.json.twig, error404.json.twig
```

But still i am not able to get those templates

I want it for access denied exception

```
 Token does not have the required roles.
403 Forbidden - AccessDeniedHttpException
1 linked Exception:

    AccessDeniedException »
```

Comment: Are you trying this under the prod environment or the dev environment?

Comment: As Carlos guesses, these custom pages are only displayed in PROD environment !

Answer (score 2):

If i were you i'd customize the `error403.html.twig` in the following folder `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error403.html.twig`

I guess you've mistaken the format of this file (`json` instead of `html`)

Also, make sure that you've cleared the cache (`php app/console ca:cl`) and that you are in prod environement.

Comment: You don't need the prod environment, just disable the debug mode: $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false); and use "php app/console cache:clear --no-debug" to clear the cache...and don't forget to switch back to the debug mode once you've done with the error pages! ;)

Answer (score 0):

A more recent update for this.  I found that in Symfony 2.8.x, the template you need to override is called `exception.html.twig`.

I did so by adding the following file in this path.

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/exception.html.twig
```

You can find the original in this folder here:

```
vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception
```